# To print table of factorials and their sum up to n using while loop. i need the sum of all the factorials

Tags: oracle, plsql, sum, factorial, digits

```
    //initializing  variables
            **DECLARE**
            i number:=1;
            n number;
            Fact number:=1;
            s number:=0;
    //declaring variables   
            **BEGIN**
            n:=&number;
    //starting the while loop
            while i>n
            loop
            Fact := Fact*i;
            dbms_output.put_line(i || ' factorial = ' || Fact);
            i:=i+1;
            s:=s+Fact; // this doesn't work? why
            **END** loop; // the loop ends
            dbms_output.put_line('Sum of the digits is: ' ||s);
            **END**; // the program ends
            /
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from syntax errors, it looks that `while` condition you used was wrong. Not `i > n`, but `i <= n`.

When fixed, this is the outcome:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    i     number := 1;
  3    n     number;
  4    fact  number := 1;
  5    s     number := 0;
  6  begin
  7    n := &par_number;
  8    while i <= n loop
  9      fact := fact * i;
 10      dbms_output.put_line(i
 11                           || ' factorial = '
 12                           || fact);
 13      i := i + 1;
 14      s := s + fact;
 15    end loop;
 16
 17    dbms_output.put_line('Sum of the digits is: ' || s);
 18  end;
 19  /
Enter value for par_number: 3
1 factorial = 1
2 factorial = 2
3 factorial = 6
Sum of the digits is: 9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the purpose of pl/sql is providing easy interface to SQL I provide an SQL based solution. This could be done with a single SQL statement, except for the printing the results. With that requirement the following uses a cursor loop strictly to provide the print functionality.

```
set serveroutput on 
declare
  total_factorial number; 
begin 
    for factorial in 
        ( with fact (f1, f2, fs, n) as 
             ( select 1, 1, 1, 0 from dual 
                union all 
                select f2 
                     , (n+1)*f2  
                     , fs+ (n+1)*f2 
                     , n+1
                  from fact            
                 where n < &N_FAC
              )
         select n, f2, fs
           from fact
       )
    loop
        total_factorial := factorial.fs;
        dbms_output.put_line( to_char(factorial.n,'fm990') ||' factorial is ' ||  
                              to_char(factorial.f2)
                            );
    end loop; 
    
    dbms_output.put_line('Sum of the digits is: ' || total_factorial);
end ;
```

**results:**  
0 factorial is 1  
1 factorial is 1  
2 factorial is 2  
3 factorial is 6  
Sum of the digits is: 10

Note: The results for "Sum of the digits" differ from the answer by @Littlefoot. This accomodates 0! which is defined as 1. You can remove that by changing  
select 1, 1, 1, 0 from dual  to  select 1, 1, 1, 1 from dual